# variables won't get updated when using awk within shell script loop

Tags: shell, awk

I tried to create a script to generate a list of commit id form git.

```
START_INDEX=0
while [ ${START_INDEX} -lt ${#VERSION_ARRAY[@]} ] 
do
    CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code)
    NEXT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code)
    COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]=$(git log master | \
    awk -v start_line=${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE}\
    -v end_line=${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE}\
    'NR == start_line, NR == end_line {if(match($0, "commit")) print $2}')
    START_INDEX=$((START_INDEX+1))
done
```

The issue is that the variables, "start_line" and "end_line" will not get updated.
I have tried to echo "CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE" and "NEXT_COMMIT_LINE", and those are updated through the loop process.
Anything I did wrong?

The whole Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUP_BRANCH_TAILING="_patch_backup"
NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION=$(git branch | awk -F '_' '/new_code.*[0-9]$/{print $3}')
echo "New code version ${NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION}"
LATEST_SVN_VERSION=$(git log master | awk '/trunk\@/{first=match($2, "@")+1; s=substr($2, first, length($2)); print s; exit;}')
echo "The latest svn version at master branch is ${LATEST_SVN_VERSION}"
NUMBER_OF_PATCH_TO_APPLY=$((LATEST_SVN_VERSION-NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION))
if [ ${LATEST_SVN_VERSION} -gt ${NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION} ] ; then
    #make sure the branch is switched to new_code_XXX
    if [ -z "$(git branch | grep -i "^* new_code_.*[0-9]$")" ] ; then
        echo "Switching to new_code branch..."
        #git checkout new_code_${NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION}
    fi

    #create a backup branch witht the tailing of patch_backup
    if [ -z "$(git branch | grep -i "new_code_.*${BACKUP_BRANCH_TAILING}$")" ] ; then
        echo "Creating backup..."
        #git branch new_code_${NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION}${BACKUP_BRANCH_TAILING}
    fi

    #create an array of version which are to be patched to the new_code branch
    START_INDEX=0
    echo "Debug: start index, ${START_INDEX}, end index ${END_INDEX}"
    while [ ${START_INDEX} -lt ${NUMBER_OF_PATCH_TO_APPLY} ]
    do
        VERSION_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]=$((NEW_CODE_BCH_VERSION+START_INDEX+1))
        echo "start index for creating version array${START_INDEX} verion ${VERSION_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]}"
        START_INDEX=$((START_INDEX+1))
    done

    #create an array of commit ids associated with respective version
    #START_INDEX=0
    #while [ ${START_INDEX} -lt ${#VERSION_ARRAY[@]} ]
    for (( START_INDEX=0; ${START_INDEX} < ${#VERSION_ARRAY[@]}; ++START_INDEX)); 
    do
        #Find out the range between two commits
        CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE=$(git log master | awk -v pat="trunk@${VERSION_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]}" ' $0 ~ pat {print NR}')
        if [ $((START_INDEX+1)) -lt ${#VERSION_ARRAY[@]} ] ; then
            NEXT_COMMIT_LINE=$(git log master | awk -v pat="trunk@${VERSION_ARRAY[$((START_INDEX+1))]}" '$0 ~ pat {print NR}')
        else
            NEXT_COMMIT_LINE=1
        fi
        echo "current line: ${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE}, newer line: ${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE}"
        #Find the commit id between two commit 
        COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]=$(git log master |awk  -v  start_line="${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE}" \
                                         -v end_line="${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE}" \
                                         'BEGIN {print "[BEGIN]:start line:"start_line ", end line:" end_line} \
                                         NR == start_line, NR== end_line {if(match($0, "commit")) print $2}')

        echo "start index for creating version array${START_INDEX} commit ID: ${COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${ARRAY_INDEX}]}"
        #START_INDEX=$((START_INDEX+1))
    done

    #patch each commit id

    #rename the branch name

else
    echo "There is no newer commits at the master branch!"
fi
```

Below is a small section of the result

```
current line: 66, newer line: 58
start index for creating version array14 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 58, newer line: 50
start index for creating version array15 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 50, newer line: 42
start index for creating version array16 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 42, newer line: 34
start index for creating version array17 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 34, newer line: 26
start index for creating version array18 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 26, newer line: 18
start index for creating version array19 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 18, newer line: 7
start index for creating version array20 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
current line: 7, newer line: 1
start index for creating version array21 commit ID: [BEGIN]:begin line:184, end line:192
af9e83e393b1f627d8d16a1c43c3a365b8ed5aec
```

Comment: well, i made a mistake at my debugging message where I use the non-existing variables. Therefore, I kept getting the same SHA. Though, as I print start_line and end_line variables inside BEGIN. I always get the same result. Despite that, I get the correct SHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't enclose your command substitution properly:

```
COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]=$(git log master | \
awk -v start_line=${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE})\
-v end_line=${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE}\
'NR == start_line, NR == end_line {if(match($0, "commit")) print $2}'
```

It should be:

```
COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${START_INDEX}]=$(git log master | awk -v start_line=${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE} \
-v end_line=${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE} \
'NR == start_line, NR == end_line {if(match($0, "commit")) print $2}')
```

And be careful when moving parts of your command to the next line as you might join two arguments as one.

Another simpler version:

```
for (( START_INDEX = 0; START_INDEX < ${#VERSION_ARRAY[@]}; ++START_INDEX )); do
    CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code)
    NEXT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code)
    COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[START_INDEX]=$(git log master | awk -v start_line="${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE}" \
        -v end_line="${NEXT_COMMIT_LINE}" \
        'NR == start_line, NR == end_line {if(match($0, "commit")) print $2}')
done
```

Update:

On the line

```
echo "start index for creating version array${START_INDEX} commit ID: ${COMMIT_SHA_ARRAY[${ARRAY_INDEX}]}"
```

`ARRAY_INDEX` probably should be `START_INDEX`.

Comment: Hi konsolebox, my apology, that was my typo. I did have an enclosing bracket there. The bash doesn't complain for any syntax error. thnx for the advice on the next line part :)

Comment: @user2817665 I'm not sure if that was just a typo since you ended your bracket here: `awk -v start_line=${CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE})`

Comment: yeah it was my bad. my script is on different machine, so i can't just copy and paste to the website. again, i'm sorry that it makes u confused

Comment: @user2817665 You can try my suggestion and see if that could fix things for you. There were some variables you didn't properly quote as well.

Comment: If it still doesn't work I bet the problem already lies on `CURRENT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code) NEXT_COMMIT_LINE=$(some code)` or the awk code itself.